# Solr add Document fails after adding updateHandler

Tags: xml, solr

I have following configurations in  solrconfig.xml

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="concat" >
<processor class="solr.ConcatFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
<str name="fieldName">spell_field</str>
</processor>
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
<requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="update.chain">concat</str>
</lst>
</requestHandler>
```

When  i try to add a doc  in solr it shows no error but document doesnt get added. If  i remove updateRequestProcessorChain it works fine.

P.S - `spell_field` is present in my schema.xml

Code:

```
SolrClient solrClient = new HttpSolrClient("url"); 
SolrInputDocument solrDoc = new SolrInputDocument();
solrDoc.setField("price",5); 
solrDoc.setField("name",7); 
solrDoc.setField("id", 2); 
UpdateResponse response = solrClient.add(solrDoc); 
solrClient.commit(true,true);
```

Comment: Are you sure your code works? Have you checked the logs for any exceptions? Alternately, post your code.

Comment: @BinoyDalal: PFB the code I use for adding  docs               SolrClient solrClient = new HttpSolrClient("url");
SolrInputDocument solrDoc =  new SolrInputDoocument();  
solrDoc.setField("price",5);
solrDoc.setField("name",7);
solrDoc.setField("id", 2);
UpdateResponse response = solrClient.add(solrDoc);
solrClient.commit(true,true);

Comment: Even a simple delete  command like solrClient.deleteByQuery("id:1") is not working.  However if  i  remove the updateRequestProcessorChain  it works fine

Comment: In the second line, you use `SolrInputDocument solrDoc = new SolrInputDoocument();` where SolrInputDocument is spelled wrong. Is this a typo here or is this your actual code?

Comment: typo. I retyped my  code here somade a mistake.